# How to correct install and use plugin installed via composer

Tags: cakephp-3.0, acl

I installed a cakephp 3 app via composer from the root of my website `c:wamp/www/my_app`, and I developed untill i need to implement acl.

I installed the acl plugin for cakephp 3 via composer for the same path `c:/wamp/www/myapp` and i configured it, was everything well, but when i test the implementation of acl, i get the following error:

> Missing Component, Create the class AclComponent below in file: src\Controller\Component\AclComponent.php

and seems to be true, theres no such file in the above location, instead the file is in `vendor/cakephp/acl/src/controller/component`.

Was investigating and i find that composer doesnt install plugins in a cake default path, theres many articles about, but how doi correct my installation? I already did all the stuff to implement the access control lists.

Thanks in advance [error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxV8G.png)

Comment: Let me guess, you are loading the component in your controller like this `$this->loadComponent('Acl')`?

Comment: No @ndm, im loading acl inside Auth like this: `$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'authorize' => [
                'Acl.Actions' => ['actionPath' => 'controllers/']
            ] ...`

Comment: Then this looks like a bug in the ACL plugin, you may want to report that [**over at GitHub**](https://github.com/cakephp/acl/issues). The authorize object doesn't use plugin notation for loading the component: **https://github.com/cakephp/acl/blob/0.2.1/src/Auth/ActionsAuthorize.php#L38**

Comment: Im not sure that this is a bug, i loaded the component in a diferent way: `$this->loadComponent('Acl.Acl'); and is working now!`

Comment: The code says "_If AclComponent is not already loaded it will be loaded using the Controller's ComponentRegistry_", so if loading the component yourself fixes the problem, then this looks like a bug to me.